# Using Dynamic Or Expressions in C#

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I use the dynamic filter in my program like following solution:

```
public static IQueryable<T> MyFilter<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable) where T : class ,IModel
{
        var someIds = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
        var userId = 2;

        Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate1 = e => someIds.Contains(e.Id);
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate2 = e => e.UserId==userId;
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate3 = e => e.CreatedDate != null;

        var pred1 = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Or(predicate1, predicate2));
        var pred2 = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Or(pred1, predicate3));


        var result = queryable
            .Where(pred2);

        return result;
    }
```

The `IModel` is like this:

```
Public interface IModel{
   int Id { get; set; }
   int UserId { get; set; }
   DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

but, I get this error:

> The binary operator Or is not defined for the types 'System.Func`2[AnyClass,System.Boolean]' and 'System.Func`2[AnyClass,System.Boolean]'.

at this line:

```
var pred1 = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Or(predicate1, predicate2));
```

How can I solve this problem?

beforehand appreciate any help

Comment: This `someIds.Contains(e.Id)` is not correct. `IModel` does not contain an `Id` field.

Comment: Why do you use Expression instead of just Func?

Comment: You are so much far from what you need... You must use `Expression.OrElse`, because `Expression.Or` is the `|` operator.

Comment: BUT the real problem is that you can't join Lambda expressions (`predicate1`, `2`, `3`) in that way. Joining expressions is complex, because the input parameter for `predicate1`, `2`, `3` is different (it's like it is `e1`, `e2`, `e3` instead of `e`), and `pred1` and `pred2` will have an `e4` and `e5`.

Comment: @AlexVoskresenskiy Because he is using a `IQueryable`, that works only on `Expression`.

Comment: ok @Alex Voskresenskiy, thanks for your reply.
I test that earlier, but I get this error:
The LINQ experssion node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.
do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: thanks @xanatos, your solution is not work...

Comment: @pedram because as I've said, it's more complex than simply changing `Or` to `OrElse`

Comment: @xanatos hm, i cannot find out, if you pass Func to IQueryable then it won't translate it to sql, but it'll get all data and then apply func's on c# side to it?

Comment: @AlexVoskresenskiy Yep, because you'll use the `Enumerable.Where`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create one predicate without Expression.Or:

```
public static IQueryable<T> MyFilter<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable) where T : class ,IModel
    {
        var someIds = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        var userId = 2;

        var result = queryable
            .Where(e => someIds.Contains(e.Id) || e.UserId == userId || e.CreatedDate != null);

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: You don't even need the intermediate `predicate` variable. It would be shorter and cleaner to just put the expression inside the `Where` call.

Comment: ok,that's right. but we are many predicate that should be add to my  expression.
anyway,your answer is correct and solved my problem,thanks ;)

Answer (score 5):

As I've written in my comments, there are two different problems:

- You must use `Expression.OrElse`, because `Expression.Or` is the `|` operator.
- BUT the real problem is that you can't join Lambda expressions (`predicate1`, `2`, `3`) in that way. Joining expressions is complex, because the input parameters for `predicate1`, `2`, `3` is different (it's like it is `e1`, `e2`, `e3` instead of `e`), and `pred1` and `pred2` will have an `e4` and `e5` input parameter, so you have to to some expression replacing.

The solution:

```
// Note that we only need the Body!
Expression pred1 = Expression.OrElse(Expression.OrElse(predicate1.Body, predicate2.Body), predicate3.Body);

// We change all the predicate2.Parameters[0] to predicate1.Parameters[0] and
// predicate3.Parameters[0] to predicate1.Parameters[0]

var replacer = new SimpleExpressionReplacer(
    /* from */ new[] { predicate2.Parameters[0], predicate3.Parameters[0] }, 
    /* to */ new[] { predicate1.Parameters[0], predicate1.Parameters[0] });

pred1 = replacer.Visit(pred1);

// We use for the new predicate the predicate1.Parameters[0]
var pred2 = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(pred1, predicate1.Parameters[0]);

var result = queryable.Where(pred2);
```

and the `SimpleExpressionReplacer`:

```
// A simple expression visitor to replace some nodes of an expression 
// with some other nodes
public class SimpleExpressionReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public readonly Dictionary<Expression, Expression> Replaces;

    public SimpleExpressionReplacer(Dictionary<Expression, Expression> replaces)
    {
        Replaces = replaces;
    }

    public SimpleExpressionReplacer(IEnumerable<Expression> from, IEnumerable<Expression> to)
    {
        Replaces = new Dictionary<Expression, Expression>();

        using (var enu1 = from.GetEnumerator())
        using (var enu2 = to.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (true)
            {
                bool res1 = enu1.MoveNext();
                bool res2 = enu2.MoveNext();

                if (!res1 || !res2)
                {
                    if (!res1 && !res2)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    if (!res1)
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentException("from shorter");
                    }

                    throw new ArgumentException("to shorter");
                }

                Replaces.Add(enu1.Current, enu2.Current);
            }
        }
    }

    public SimpleExpressionReplacer(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        Replaces = new Dictionary<Expression, Expression> { { from, to } };
    }

    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        Expression to;

        if (node != null && Replaces.TryGetValue(node, out to))
        {
            return base.Visit(to);
        }

        return base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

### Use `PredicateBuilder`

Either copy the source of the class from [here](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx), or install the [LINQKit NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit/) (which has a dependency on Entity Framework), to get the `PredicateBuilder` class. It's simple to dynamically chain expression together with it:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<int>();
predicate = predicate.Or(x => x > 5);
predicate = predicate.Or(x => x % 2 == 0);
predicate = predicate.Or(x => x == 42 );

var queryable = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }.AsQueryable();
var result = queryable.Where(predicate);
```