# Dynamically include/exclude fields in where clause LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I wanted to include or exclude the fields in where condition dynamically.

I am having a grid with 5 columns, each column have a property called `CanSearchable`. If the user enters searchstring in textbox and clicks Searech button,
I need to search the string in the columns whose CanSearchable property is true. Once the search button is clicked I have sent the SearchString and columns to be searched (column1, column2, column4) to controller.

Here is my search linq.

```
staffs = staffs.Where(s => s.column1.Contains(model.SearchString) ||
                                               s.column2.Contains(model.SearchString) ||
                                                s.column4.Contains(model.SearchString));
```

I wanted to create this part dynamically based on the columns to be searched.

```
    s.column1.Contains(model.SearchString) || s.column2.Contains(model.SearchString) ||
 s.column4.Contains(model.SearchString)
```

Please suggest me the solution.

Comment: Instead of describing how your grid looks like please provide real code which you use to define whether some column is searchable. As I can see, model contains only search string. Is there other properties in model? How do you pass those values? As list of strings? As booleans?

Comment: If you are doing a query against a DB (so `staffs` is a `IQueryable<>`), from http://stackoverflow.com/q/29467698/613130 use my solution or Allon Guralnek solution.

Comment: What is `staffs`? is it a `List`/array or is it a query on the DB?

Answer (score 2):

If the column you want to search is set as `CanSearchable`,
Then your requirment is quite easy

```
  staffs = staffs.Where(s =>
           s.column1.CanSearchable && s.column1.Content.Contains(model.SearchString)||                                                   
           s.column2.CanSearchable && s.column2.Content.Contains(model.SearchString)|| 
           s.column3.CanSearchable && s.column3.Content.Contains(model.SearchString)||                                              
           s.column4.CanSearchable && s.column4.Content.Contains(model.SearchString));
```

Comment: Did the PO say column1 is string??? Read the Question before you degrade

Comment: What another type you expect to have a method `.Contains(stringArg)`?

Comment: Don't worry, I'll remove downvote and change it to upvote as soon as I see that answer is correct

Comment: All lists has contains(stringArg)..[Sergey](http://stackoverflow.com/users/470005/sergey-berezovskiy).. 
But I see your confusion here. The PO needed one more type. 
Like column1={ bool CanSearchable, string content }

Comment: Yep, lets wait and see details. Sorry if my downvote offends you.